# When I implement hive library for save theme mode, I have null error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

Here is an original code of hive.db.dev  . I tried to fix it but I could not. I tried to put "?" and "!" but it did not fix it. Here is the code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

const darkModeBox = 'darkModeTutorial';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox(darkModeBox);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: Hive.box(darkModeBox).listenable(),
      builder: (context, box, widget) {
        var darkMode = box.get('darkMode', defaultValue: false);
        return MaterialApp(
          themeMode: darkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
          darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Switch(
                value: darkMode,
                onChanged: (val) {
                  box.put('darkMode', !darkMode);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

also here is error message  =>

> Error: The method 'get' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'.
>
> ```
>            var darkMode = box.get('darkMode', defaultValue: false);  
>                               ^^^
> ```
>
> Error: The method 'put' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'put'.
>
> ```
>                     box.put('darkMode', !darkMode); 
>                         ^^^
> ```
>
> Restarted application in 255ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clear the error you need to tell `ValueListenableBuilder` what data type its dealing with, in this case it's of type `Box`.

```
return ValueListenableBuilder<Box>(...) // adding <Box>
```

That alone should fix it.

However I would approach this a bit differently so that you're not accessing the `Hive` box directly from the `ValueListenableBuilder`. In general I suggest avoiding direct interactions with core stuff like databases directly from the UI.

You can create a `ThemeStorage` class that a simple boolean `isDarkMode`. What that changes, it will trigger a rebuild and also stores the updated value. Upon app restart, it will default to whatever is stored. The fields are `static` because you never need to create a new object of this class.

```
class ThemeStorage {
  static ValueNotifier<bool> isDarkMode =
      ValueNotifier(Hive.box(darkModeBox).get('darkMode') ?? false);

  static void toggleDarkMode() {
    isDarkMode.value = !isDarkMode.value; // this will trigger a rebuild
    
    Hive.box(darkModeBox)
        .put('darkMode', isDarkMode.value); // this stores the updated value
  }
}
```

Now your `MyApp` is simplified and all it cares about is a simple `bool`. If in the future you want more complex themes you can define them in the `ThemeStorage` class and instead of building from a `bool` you could build off a `ThemeData` variable.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      // be sure to always put data type here
    return ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
      valueListenable: ThemeStorage.isDarkMode,
      builder: (_, isDarkMode, __) {
        // here isDarkMode is a bool and not an Object because of inserting bool above
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: isDarkMode ? ThemeData.dark() : ThemeData.light(),
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Switch(
                value: isDarkMode,
                onChanged: (val) => ThemeStorage.toggleDarkMode(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```